# Can map_server connect to costmap_2d directly with message or service?

Tags: navigation, mapping, map-server, costmap-2d

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi, all, I want to implement a node that implementing some functionalities based on the map which have to use the costmap_2d. I hope that costmap_2d should received the message from map_server. However, I found there is no direct message exchange betweer map_server and costmap_2d, i.e. not topics or services between them. It seems that the move_base node has to launched beforehand.

Does somebody know that there is some direct way to connect them by launching only map_server and costmap_2d node?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/197486/can-map_server-connect-to-costmap_2d-directly-with-message-or-service?/) by [scopus](https://answers.ros.org/users/8561/scopus/) on ROS Answers with karma: 279 on 2014-11-15

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You should be able to create an instance of costmap_2d that directly subscribes to the map. If you're using Hydro or later, make sure you are using the StaticMap layer. If you are using a version earlier than hydro, make sure ~static_map is set to true.

---

Originally posted by [David Lu](https://answers.ros.org/users/19/david-lu/) with karma: 10932 on 2014-11-15

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0